# Leading term ideal irreducible iff the ideal is irreducible?

Tags: commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, monomial-ideals

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field. Given an ideal $I \subset \mathbb{K}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ and a monomial order we can consider the ideal $LT(I) = (lt(f) \ | \ f\in I )$, where $lt(f)$ denotes the leading term of the polynomial  $f$. 
It can be shown that if $LT(I)$ is prime then $I$ is prime, but the viceversa does not hold (e.g. $(x^2 + 1)\subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$).
I wonder then  what kind of relation there is between the irreducibility of $LT(I)$ and the irreducibility of $I$.

Formally my question is:

> $LT(I)$  irreducible $\Rightarrow$ $I$ irreducible?
>    $I$  irreducible $\Rightarrow$ $LT(I)$ irreducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one variable, $LT(I)$ will always be irreducible, since $I=(x^n)$ is irreducible. Hence the answer to your first question is negative, i.e. take $I=(x^2-1) = (x-1) \cap (x+1)$. This is not irreducible, but $LT(I)=(x^2)$ is.

The second question can also be answered negatively:
$I=(xy-1) \subset K[x,y]$ is irreducible, because it is prime. $LT(I)=(xy)$ is not.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to see that $(xy-1)$ is prime without expoloiting the isomorphism $K[x,y]/(xy-1) \backsimeq (K[x])_{x}$? And what about primality? Does $I$ primary implie $LT(I)$ primary?

Comment: $xy-1 \in (K[x])[y]$ is primitive and linear, hence irreducible. In a factorial ring an irreducible element generates a prime ideal.